# OWL: how to limit the range of a value

Tags: owl

For example, I need to describe a dog between age 1 and 4. How do I restrict the value range of a property? There are minCardinality and maxCardinality for number of property. But not suitable for my example.

```
<xs:element name="age">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
      <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
      <xs:maxInclusive value="4"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

As an concrete example, how to translate above xsd to owl?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a qualified cardinality restriction directly as a local class restriction.  For example, to define that an amoeba has an age range of 1 to 4, use the following:

```
<rdfs:subClassOf>
  <owl:Restriction>
    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://example.org/things#age"/>
    <owl:maxQualifiedCardinality rdf:datatype="xs:nonNegativeInteger">4</owl:maxQualifiedCardinality>
    <owl:onDataRange rdf:resource="http://example.org/things#Amoeba"/>
  </owl:Restriction>
</rdfs:subClassOf>
<rdfs:subClassOf>
  <owl:Restriction>
    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://example.org/things#age"/>
    <owl:minQualifiedCardinality rdf:datatype="xs:nonNegativeInteger">1</owl:minQualifiedCardinality>
    <owl:onDataRange rdf:resource="http://example.org/things#Amoeba"/>
  </owl:Restriction>
</rdfs:subClassOf>
```

That's a bit difficult to read.  The equivalent Turtle serialization is considerably easier to read and manage (note the direct representation of triples.  JSON-LD is another readily consumable text serialization for RDF):

```
rdfs:subClassOf [
    rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
    owl:maxQualifiedCardinality "4"^^xs:nonNegativeInteger ;
    owl:onDataRange ex:Amoeba ;
    owl:onProperty ex:age ;
  ] ;
rdfs:subClassOf [
    rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
    owl:minQualifiedCardinality "1"^^xs:nonNegativeInteger ;
    owl:onDataRange ex:Amoeba ;
    owl:onProperty ex:age ;
  ] ;
```

Comment: what is that owl:onDataRange used for?

Comment: It specifies the the resource the cardinality restriction is applied to - hence the term "local restriction".  I.e. the minQualifiedCardinality restriction is defined as "the value of the property ex:age must be greater than one on the resource ex:Amoeba".

Answer (score 0):

You can use xsd:minInclusive and xsd:maxInclusive

```
<owl:Class rdf:ID="dog">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Restriction>
        <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#age"/>
        <owl:withRestrictions>
          <xsd:minInclusive rdf:datatype="xsd:integer">1</xsd:minInclusive>
          <xsd:maxInclusive rdf:datatype="xsd:integer">4</xsd:maxInclusive>
        </owl:withRestrictions>
      </owl:Restriction>
  </rdfs:subClassOf>
</owl:Class>
```